# What can be the best Practice for a Rapid Web Application Development?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am coming up with a web application which will be primarily based on PHP. I would like to know some of the best practices and technologies that I can make use of to come out with the app as fast as possible. My team will be working remotely, so I want to know the best ways of collaborating through web resources too. I'm expecting in here, the options or a framework of technologies that can get me a great app in a shorter time.
I've given a small example out here. Please extend my plan and give me suggestions...

1. Server Side Scripting - PHP (CakePHP for rapid development)
2. Client Side Scripting - JS (JQuery - A JS framework for rapid development and compatibility)
3. Authentication - OpenId
4. Database - MySQL (Stable and OpenSource)

I want more to be added to this list so that I code less and reuse more. Please help me out.

Reusability is the key factor. How do I leverage already available classes, frameworks, etc in an efficient way? I want to know my options.

Comment: Please consider PostgreSQL, which is also free, also open-source, and comes with the benefit of being a real RDBMS.

Comment: A very subjective question. I think you need to give us some more details on your and your team's experience. If your team has no previous knowlede of CakePHP or jQuery it will most likely not be quick. For authentication I would use one of the authentication frameworks that support the whole lot (FB, Google etc) just to be nice to your potential visitors. And a +1 for PostgrSQL but if you have a lot of expierience with MySQL and none with Potgres maybe not.

Comment: It depends on various things like budget contstraints etc. If you want to go for open source like PHP,MYsql, Apache , you need to have expert team for that. As it is remote work you should have solid source safe system for maintaining code base.

Comment: Questions like this cannot be answered.  So expect many conflicting responses.

Comment: It depends greatly on what kind of project you are trying to create. Personally I like Zend Framework, jQuery, and MySQL. Zend should have built in functionality for dealing with OpenID. At the same time you need to look at everything and determine what the right tool for the job is and what you and your team know how to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try to find a framework that suit your needs. If you want reusability, make sure you learn/understand the concept of the MVC pattern (OOP). I personally work with Zend-Framework which has a very big community.

  (However, a good practice is building your own framework. Look at other frameworks and learn about the pro's and cons.)
- Every project starts with an UML design: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language
- Don't try to invent the wheel again, for example: learn/play with the 960 css grid http://960.gs, jQuery and different database-types.
- Documentate everything!
- Test everything http://simpletest.org
- use subversion for easy access of previous versions of your project http://subversion.net

Good luck!!